# Problems with std::vector::push_back

Tags: c++, stdvector

I'm encountering some unexpected behavior with std::vector::push_back in C++. I have the following pseudocode, which I hope is clear enough to demonstrate the issue I'm seeing:

```
MyClass* myClass = new MyClass();
std::vector<MyObject*> newObjects;
myClass->VectorOperation(oldObject, newObjects);
```

The `MyClass::VectorOperation(MyObject* oldObject, std::vector<MyObject*> newObjects)` should operate as follows:

```
void MyClass::VectorOperation(MyObject* oldObject, std::vector<MyObject*> newObjects)
{
    if (// Some condition on oldObject)
    {
        newObjects->push_back(oldObject);
    }
    else
    {
        // Operations that can result in translating a single oldObject into many MyObjects, e.g.
        MyObject* newObject1 = new MyObject();
        MyObject* newObject2 = new MyObject();
        newObjects->push_back(newObject1);
        newObjects->push_back(newObject2);
    }
}
```

The issue I'm seeing is that after the successful execution of the `if` statement in  `VectorOperation`, the `newObjects` vector is empty, i.e. the `newObjects` vector should have a single entry corresponding to `oldObject`. I'm relatively new to C++, but I'm not sure what I'm missing here. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

EDIT:
I mistyped the method signature. It should be:

```
void MyClass::VectorOperation(MyObject* oldObject, std::vector<MyObject*>* newObjects)
```

Comment: Also, try to avoid manual memory management and use smart pointers.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using newObjects.push_back() rather than newObjects->push_back() ?

Comment: @JeeveshJuneja good catch, corrected the method signature.

Comment: If your function definition is expecting a pointer to a stack-allocated vector, then `myClass->VectorOperation(oldObject, newObjects);` will not work. You will need to pass the address `myClass->VectorOperation(oldObject, &newObjects);` That said, if it is heap-allocated, then your example is incomplete and we cannot help you unless you provide an actual [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `&`:

```cpp
void MyClass::VectorOperation(MyObject* oldObject, std::vector<MyObject*>& newObjects) {
//                                                                       ^
    if (// Some condition on oldObject)
    {
        newObjects.push_back(oldObject);
//                ^ Guess you meant . instead of ->.
    }
    ...
}
```

Now when you pass `newObjects` vector you copy it, so `push_back` happens to the copied vector, not original. If you add `&` you will pass `newObjects` by reference, so vector won't be copied and `oldObject` will be pushed back to the original vector.

Comment: Thank you! This is the correct answer for my general question but unfortunately, I believe I've uncovered the root of the problem. The ```MyClass::VectorOperation``` function is native C++, while the code that calls this class/function is managed C++.